# What Is The Domain Restriction Of A Set Upon Another Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have come across a problem and I am not sure that I understand the concept of what is trying to be done.  I am studying computer science and in our Mathematics class, this problem was posed.

$$f = \{1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 4, 3 \mapsto 6, 4 \mapsto 9, 5 \mapsto 11 \}$$
  $$ and $$
$$ S = \{1,3,5\}$$
$$ determine $$
$$ S \triangleleft f$$

I understand that the left triangle means domain restriction but I do not understand what I would have to do to answer this question.

Many thanks in advance to those who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$, as given, has the domain $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The problem asks you to determine the function $g$ whose domain is $\{1,3,5\}$, and $g(x)=f(x)$ for every such $x$.

Comment: thank you, I understand now.  In words it would be a f is restricted in its input to only the elements in S..?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.